# I need some help to optimize this code that read annotations in php classes

Tags: php, regex, optimization, annotations

I've written this class with one static method that read annotations and convert them in one array. So, this code:

```
/**
 * @MyAnnotation(attr1=value,attr2=value);
 */
class MyClass
{

    public static function readMyAnnotation()
    {
        $classComment = (new ReflectionClass(get_class()))->getDocComment();
        $comments = explode("\n", $classComment);
        foreach ($comments as $item) {
            if(strpos($item, "@")) {
                $comment = explode("@", $item);
                $annotation = explode(")", $comment[1])[0];
                $annotationName = explode("(", $annotation)[0];
                $annotationValue = explode("(", $annotation)[1];
                $annotationParams = explode(",", $annotationValue);
                $params = [];
                foreach ($annotationParams as $item) {
                    $params[explode("=", $item)[0]] = explode("=", $item)[1];
                }
                print_r([$annotationName => $params]);
            }
        }
    }

}

MyClass::readMyAnnotation();
```

will output this:

```
Array ( [MyAnnotation] => Array ( [attr1] => value [attr2] => value ) );
```

Can someone help me optimizing this code using regular expressions? I am not able to write good code with regex. My code works fine, but I dont like it!

```
/**
 * @MyAnnotation(attr1=value,attr2=value);
 */
class MyClass
{

    public static function readMyAnnotation()
    {
        $classComment = (new ReflectionClass(get_class()))->getDocComment();
        $comments = explode("\n", $classComment);
        foreach ($comments as $item) {
            if(strpos($item, "@")) {
                /* ?????????????? */
                print_r([$annotationName => $params]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want regexes, why do you think they would optimize your code?

Comment: Can you show us what `$item` looks like internally in your question? Ideally to get some help, it would be useful if you link a working example on Codepad or similar (http://codepad.org/) - anything that makes it easier for people to run your code is good!

Comment: @Bergi, 'couse 1 if and 5 explode can be written with 1 regex.

Comment: @halfer, each $items is a single line of comment.

Comment: @Simone: So why don't you just do it? Do your regexes not work any more (if so, which ones have you tried)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php function `preg_match`, it will store matched substring in parenthesis `(.*)` to `$match_name[1]`:

```
preg_match("/\@(.*)\(/",$item,$match_name);
$annotationName = $match_name[1];
preg_match("/\((.*)\)/",$item,$match_values);
$values = explode(",",$match_values[1]);
foreach ($values as $value) {
  $exploded = explode("=", $value);
  $params[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
}
```

Comment: This helps me a lot. Than k you.